# Failure with heroku pg:backups restore for nodejs app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, amazon-s3

I have tried to populate my postgres database on heroku numerous times via a dump file on Amazon S3.  The heroku pg:backups restore fails with this explanation: "aborting: could not write to output stream: Get : 301 response missing Location header".

Here's the command line with the DATABASE_URL variable (name/pswd edited):

`$ heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stoxx/stoxx_db.dump' DATABASE_URL`

`DATABASE_URL: postgres://zi...tv:vc...fw_t@ec2-54-163-230-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4t...h23`

My node app on heroku launches properly, and the local version connects with the local pg database.  The error implies an issue when trying to write into the db on heroku ("could not write to output stream").  The dump file is public on AWS and the AWS url was copied directly from the bucket properties list.  48 hours into this...  Any help greatly appreciated!!